# Java Eclipse Class editor disappeared

Tags: java, eclipse

I don't really know, should I ask this question here or not, but I'm in trouble. My eclipse window looks like that now:

[image]

And I can not open window where I can edit class. When I double click on class name (on left side: Package Explorer), nothing changes on main window, the editor doesn't appear. But on right side menu: Outline, it opens that class as you can see on picture. I tried close and run eclipse, tried to reset Java perspective, but nothing changes...

Can anybody help me?

**SOLUTION:**

I found solution. Window - > New Window. And it worked

Comment: It is possibile to have the workspace broken.

Comment: This has happened to me before, Try one of these: change perspective (say from `Java` to `Java Browsing`),  Restart Eclipse or Window->Reset Prespective and restart eclipse.

Comment: I tried that too, changed to debug and java browsing but still nothing...

Answer (score -1):

Open the Error View and check if an error has been or is added when you try to open a class. If yes, try to correct the situation by googling the error or posting the contents of the error to SO.

The Error View can be opened by clicking `Window > Show View > Error Log`or via binding `Alt+Shift+Q, L`.

Alternatively, you can try to start Eclipse with the `-clean` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for helping, but I've found solution and updated main question :)

Comment: Good. Have a nice day then! :)